# Classes treated as Ids

Tags: jquery, class

I'm creating a stripped down blog feature for a page. On each page I'll have 10 blog posts, each with "Read More" text which will allow the user to click showing additional content. I know I could create 10 different Id's, but the jQuery would be sloppy.

Is there a way I can only show the text for the blog post which is applicable to the "Read More" option?

Currently if the user clicks on "Read More" for the first blog it will not only show the hidden text for the first blog, but the second and I only want it to show for the first. And when the user clicks on the second "Read-More" option show only the additional content for the second blog.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks!

```js
function() {
  "use strict";

  $('.read-more').click(function() {
    $('.hidden-text').slideDown('slow');
    $('.read-more').hide();
  });

  $('.read-less').click(function() {
    $('.hidden-text').slideUp('slow', function() {
      $('.read-more').show();
    }); {);
  });
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}

span:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro-p">
  <p>Text Content shown immediately for BLOG 1. <span class="read-more">Read Full Post</span></p>
</div>

<div class="hidden-text">
  <p>Text which is hidden unless Read More Text is clicked. <span class="read-less">Read Less</span></p>
</div>

<div class="intro-p">
  <p>Text Content shown immediately for BLOG 2. <span class="read-more">Read Full Post</span></p>
</div>

<div class="hidden-text">
  <p>Text which is hidden unless Read More Text is clicked. <span class="read-less">Read Less</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`closest()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim8-CtsIbVAhWLMI8KHaW5BxUQFgi-ATAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fclosest%2F&usg=AFQjCNGkhpVv76EWvWWYjEID4qvdUghHMQ) parent match

1. Its next element of the readmore.so you could match with closest parent and match the [`next()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk1Lm8sIbVAhXLNI8KHYxIDQ0QFggzMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fnext%2F&usg=AFQjCNE498BhQOD1vTQGmOyAhS4eKba-Pw) `hidden-text` element
2. Same process do with the `read-less` also using `[prev()`][3](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU0N61sIbVAhUJvo8KHalKDysQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fprev%2F&usg=AFQjCNGspK4PUwirEg4ySnH2e9WTzDqnmg)

```js
  $('.read-more').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.intro-p').next('.hidden-text').slideDown('slow');
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $('.read-less').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.hidden-text').slideUp('slow', function() {
      $(this).closest('.hidden-text').prev('.intro-p').find('.read-more').show();
    });
  });
```

```css
span {
  color: green;
}

span:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.hidden-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML:
<div class="intro-p">
  <p>Text Content shown immediately for BLOG 1. <span class="read-more">Read Full Post</span></p>
</div>

<div class="hidden-text">
  <p>Text which is hidden unless Read More Text is clicked. 1<span class="read-less">Read Less</span></p>
</div>

<div class="intro-p">
  <p>Text Content shown immediately for BLOG 2. <span class="read-more">Read Full Post</span></p>
</div>

<div class="hidden-text">
  <p>Text which is hidden unless Read More Text is clicked. 2<span class="read-less">Read Less</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
$('.read-more').click(function() {
   /* Find the nearest parent with class "intro-p" 
    * and then showing up the next element (associated element in our case) */
    $(this).closest(".intro-p").next().slideDown('slow'); 
    $(this).hide(); // Hide clicked link
});

$('.read-less').click(function() {
   // Find the nearest parent with class "hidden-text" to slide up
    $(this).closest('.hidden-text').slideUp('slow', function() {
        // Finding the appropriate element to show
        $(this).closest('.hidden-text').prev().find('.read-more').show();
    });
});
```

For tweaking - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qhWPhJDSNVftC91RnIDD?p=preview)

For reference - [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)